# Check if an object is also of another more specific type?

Tags: objective-c

I am loping an array of object that are of a type. More specific types that inherit this type. How do I check if an object is of a certain more specific type?

In the example below I am trying to check if an animal is also an elephant.

```
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < allAnimals.count; i++) {
            Animal *animal = allAnimals[i];

            // Check if animal is Elefant?                
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isKindOfClass` method for it

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < allAnimals.count; i++) {
    Animal *animal = allAnimals[i];

    if([animal isKindOfClass:[Elephant class]])
        NSLog(@"Yes it is an Elephant");
}
```

I have assumed `Elephant` as a `class` here